# How to increase a variable in tkinter,python

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to increase a variable inside a function, but I cannot find how to do it with a tkinter var
the code is below:

```py
counter = IntVar()

counter.set(0)

def addonclick (button1):

    entryBox.insert(counter.get(),button1)

    counter
```

Comment: you can make it a class, add argument to the function. Could you provide a Minimal Working Example?

Comment: Can you provide the full code? Or atleast the code of button1. Why dont you just use `command` attribute in `tkinter.Button()`?

Comment: `counter.set(counter.get()+1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
counter = IntVar()

counter.set(0)

def addonclick (button1):
    counter.set(counter.get()+1)
    entryBox.insert(counter.get(),button1)
    print(counter.get())
    #output--> 1
```

Hope it will help you.